# Mounting two folders to corresponding directories within external volume?

Tags: linux, mount, fstab, bind-mount

I'm trying to mount `/etc/folder` and `/var/folder` to the same external volume UUID=xyz. This external volume already has subdirectories `etc_folder` and `var_folder` and has been formatted and available to mount. I want to change fstab and achieve something like the following, before doing "mount -a":

```
UUID=xyz:/etc_folder /etc/folder    ext4    defaults,nofail        0       2
UUID=xyz:/var_folder /var/folder    ext4    defaults,nofail        0       2
```

But this doesn't work... what exactly should I put in fstab?

Comment: Why not mount it once then put a symlink at the other location pointing to the first?

Comment: My team wants to avoid using a symlink as it's not best practice. Upon googling I think I could use 'bind' somehow but I'm not sure how

Comment: What happens on `mount -a`?

Comment: It throws me an error saying it can't find "UUID=xyz:/etc_folder", don't think it likes the syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works in /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=xyz /mnt   ext4    defaults,nofail        0       2
/mnt/var_folder   /var/folder     none    bind                      0       0
/mnt/etc_folder    /etc/folder     none    bind                      0       0
```

I just need to mount the whole volume to one location e.g. /mnt, keep it there and create binds (seems very much like a symlink).